# Отписка внутри подписки rx js

Tags: angular, rxjs

подскажите последсвия использования отписки от потока, внутри подписки на поток.
В проектах моей компании вижу такую структуру:

```
let sub = method().subscribe(() => {
   sub.unsubscribe();
   ...
})
```

Вижу что это плохо, но объяснить почему это плохо, не могу.
Помогите сформировать мысль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом нет ничего ужасного, но это не совсем по RxJS-овски.

Если observable эммитит больше одного результата, а вам нужен только один, то обычно делают так

```js
method().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
   ...
})
```

Почему это лучше? Ну как минимум тем что не нужно создавать замыкание. Для других RxJS программистов такой код выглядет чище.

Вот статья по теме от одного из ключевых контрибьютеров RxJS https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: Да я тоже советовал использовать take(1).
Просто замыкание как-то резало глаз и было чувство, что что-то не так.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Если ты уверен, что подписчик вызывается асинхронно, то это будет работать.

Но если есть вероятность синхронного вызова, то переменная `sub` ещё не будет инициализирована и при попытке отписаться произойдёт исключение, которое уронит всю подписывающуюся функцию, а сама отписка так и не будет вызвана, причём никогда.

Comment: а вот этот ответ хорош 

Answer (score 0):

А почему не сделать какой-нибудь Subject, который эмитится при ngOnDestroy и перед subscribe не писать .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe() ? (где this.unsubscribe и есть тот самый subject)

Comment: а если нужно только 1 событие?

Comment: Тогда first(), last(), take(1) в зависимости от задачи. Я, гораздно чаще, использую take(1).